# Increment LIMIT or Looping Limit

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to create a program on which the user will enter a number and it will increment it by 20 times, The problem is that it only increments up to 20 . not 20 times . i tried putting `for(;i<=count+1;i++)` but it does infinite loop. What should i do?

Is it ok to use For loop on my Program? or Another type of looping?

```
             int count=20,i;
             i=p.nextInt();

                for (;i<=count;i++){
                   System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Not sure why it's on hold. It's clear what the problem is, and what the expected results are? (And what the answer is, but that's not something for a comment.)

Comment: Yeah, Maybe i should remove the code? or edit the Question?

Comment: Why is it still on HOLD?

Comment: Always post code before posting the question. Change your loop to `for(count=0;count<=20;++count,++i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,I think I get your problem.

First, you want to increment to `i` variable. So that's great. So you certainly need `i++` in your for-loop.

```
for(..,..,..)
{
    i++;
}
```

You want to increment it `count` times, so you need a counter that holds the times you have already incremented it. But the counter can not go over the `count` value.

```
for(int incs = 0; incs < count; incs++)
{
   i++;
}
```

And that's about it:

```
public class HelloWorld {
     public static void main(String []args){
        int count=1,i;
             i=10; // i will hold your input.

                for (int incs = 0;incs < count ; incs++){
                    i++;
                   System.out.println(i);
                }
     }
}
```

I think the mistake you made was increment `count` in your loop. When you do this, it always increments and the condition of your for-loop is never met.